# Adding Meta-qt5 to Yocto

Tags: yocto

I am trying to add meta-qt5 layer to my Yocto, here am using krogoth Master. I added the line

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtbase qtbase-tools qtbase-plugins"
```

in my local.conf and i added

```
/home/user/yocto/poky/meta-qt5 \
```

in my .bb file. Now if i tried to build

```
bitbake qtbase
```

its showing error like

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'qtbase'
```

i don't know whether the steps am following is correct are not...my target machine is `MACHINE = "dra7xx-evm"`. I want to add this meta-qt5 layer... please help me regarding this am new to this..

Comment: Did you add meta-qt5 to bblayers.conf?

Comment: yeah i added...  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-ti \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-qt5 \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/openembedded-core \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/user/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-ruby \

Comment: Could post the the initial output from when you're running `bitbake`? I.e. the one showing all layers and versions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/home/user/yocto/poky/meta-qt5` is in `conf/bblayers.conf`

If this doesn't solve the issue, please post your full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Add new meta layer, try:

```
~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu $ bitbake-layers show-layers
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta  5
meta-poky             ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-poky  5
meta-oe               ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-oe  6
meta-python           ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-python  7
meta-networking       ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-networking  5
meta-java             ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-java  10
meta-yocto-bsp        ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-yocto-bsp  5
meta-b2open           ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-b2open  6

~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu $ bitbake-layers add-layer ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/meta-qt5/

~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu $ bitbake-layers show-layers
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta  5
meta-poky             ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-poky  5
meta-oe               ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-oe  6
meta-python           ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-python  7
meta-networking       ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-oe/meta-networking  5
meta-java             ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-java  10
meta-yocto-bsp        ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-yocto-bsp  5
meta-b2open           ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/../meta-b2open  6
meta-qt5              ~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu/meta-qt5  7

~/yocto/poky-krogoth/build_xyz_qemu $
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know why you added `/home/user/yocto/poky/meta-qt5 \` to local.conf file . But add the new layer to BBlayer.conf file .

Now check the name of the recipe file in the meta-qt5 layer  bitbake the recipe name also don't include  version of the recipe (if there is any ).